# Getting data from Backendless in PHP

Tags: php, getter, backendless

So I need to retreive the data from backendless and echo it properties one by one.

SO this is my Pasien.php class where there are setter and getter:

```
<?php
namespace Hospinet;

class Pasien
{
  private $Tgl_Lahir;
  private $Tgl_Masuk;
  private $Perawatan;
  private $No_Kamar;
  private $Nama_Pasien;
  private $No_Asuransi;
  private $Jenis_Asuransi;
  private $Jenis_Kamar;
  private $Id_RS;
  private $Id_Dokter;
  private $Id_Pasien;
  private $Gender;

  public function construct( $tgl_Lahir, $tgl_Masuk, $perawatan, $no_Kamar, $nama_Pasien, $no_Asuransi, $jenis_Asuransi, $jenis_Kamar, $id_RS, $id_Dokter, $id_Pasien, $gender ) {
      $this->Tgl_Lahir = $tgl_Lahir;
      $this->Tgl_Masuk = $tgl_Masuk;
      $this->Perawatan = $perawatan;
      $this->No_Kamar = $no_Kamar;
      $this->Nama_Pasien = $nama_Pasien;
      $this->No_Asuransi = $no_Asuransi;
      $this->Jenis_Asuransi = $jenis_Asuransi;
      $this->Jenis_Kamar = $jenis_Kamar;
      $this->Id_RS = $id_RS;
      $this->Id_Dokter = $id_Dokter;
      $this->Id_Pasien = $id_Pasien;
      $this->Gender = $gender;
  }

  public function getTgl_Lahir() {
    return $this->Tgl_Lahir;
  }

  public function setTgl_Lahir( $Tgl_Lahir ) {
      $this->Tgl_Lahir = $Tgl_Lahir;
  }


  public function getTgl_Masuk() {
    return $this->Tgl_Masuk;
  } 

  public function setTgl_Masuk( $Tgl_Masuk ) {
    $this->Tgl_Masuk = $Tgl_Masuk;
  }

  public function getPerawatan() {
    return $this->Perawatan;
  } 

  public function setPerawatan( $Perawatan ) {
    $this->Perawatan = $Perawatan;
  }

  public function getNo_Kamar() {
    return $this->No_Kamar;
  } 

  public function setNo_Kamar( $No_Kamar ) {
    $this->No_Kamar = $No_Kamar;
  }

  public function getNama_Pasien() {
    return $this->Nama_Pasien;
  } 

  public function setNama_Pasien( $Nama_Pasien ) {
    $this->Nama_Pasien = $Nama_Pasien;
  }

  public function getNo_Asuransi() {
    return $this->No_Asuransi;
  } 

  public function setNo_Asuransi( $No_Asuransi ) {
    $this->No_Asuransi = $No_Asuransi;
  }

  public function getJenis_Asuransi() {
    return $this->Jenis_Asuransi;
  } 

  public function setJenis_Asuransi( $Jenis_Asuransi ) {
    $this->Jenis_Asuransi = $Jenis_Asuransi;
  }

  public function getJenis_Kamar() {
    return $this->Jenis_Kamar;
  } 

  public function setJenis_Kamar( $Jenis_Kamar ) {
    $this->Jenis_Kamar = $Jenis_Kamar;
  }

  public function getId_RS() {
    return $this->Id_RS;
  } 

  public function setId_RS( $Id_RS ) {
    $this->Id_RS = $Id_RS;
  }

  public function getId_Dokter() {
    return $this->Id_Dokter;
  } 

  public function setId_Dokter( $Id_Dokter ) {
    $this->Id_Dokter = $Id_Dokter;
  }

  public function getId_Pasien() {
    return $this->Id_Pasien;
  } 

  public function setId_Pasien( $Id_Pasien ) {
    $this->Tgl_Masuk = $Tgl_Masuk;
  }

  public function getGender() {
    return $this->Gender;
  } 

  public function setGender( $Gender ) {
    $this->Gender = $Gender;
  }
}
```

I tried something like this in my index.php

```
<?php

namespace Hospinet;

use backendless\Backendless;

use backendless\services\persistence\BackendlessDataQuery;

use backendless\model\BackendlesCollection;

use Hospinet\Pasien;

include "backendless/autoload.php";

include "pasien.php";

Backendless::initApp('appid', 'REST key', 'v1');

$Pasien = new Pasien();

$result_collection = Backendless::$Persistence->of("Pasien")->find($data_query_or_relation_depth = null);

print_r( $result_collection->getAsArray() );

?>
```

And when I run it, this is what I got

```
backendless\model\BackendlessCollection Object
(

[data] => Array

(

[offset] => 0

[data] => Array

(

[0] => Array

(

[Id_Dokter] => C0E0607E

[created] => 1495593955000

[Gender] => L

[ownerId] => [Id_Pasien] => 1

[No_Asuransi] => H259030

[__meta] => {"relationRemovalIds":{},"selectedProperties":["Id_Dokter","created","Gender","ownerId","Id_Pasien","No_Asuransi","Nama_Pasien","No_Kamar","Tgl_Lahir","Perawatan","Jenis_Asuransi","Jenis_Kamar","Id_RS","___class","Tgl_Masuk","updated","objectId"],"relatedObjects":{}}

[Nama_Pasien] => Agustinus Kuncoro

[No_Kamar] => ICU-2

[Tgl_Lahir] => 29 Maret 1979

[Perawatan] => Hijau

[Jenis_Asuransi] => BPJS

[Jenis_Kamar] => ICU

[Id_RS] => 80923920

[___class] => Pasien

[Tgl_Masuk] => 17 Maret 2017

[updated] => 1495594474000

[objectId] => 347D197A-7235-04AB-FF0A-F9D5215F2F00

)

)

[nextPage] => [totalObjects] => 1

)

[stored_next_page_link] =>

)
```

Well it works, but what I want is to print the properties separately... something like this when I run the PHP code:

```
Name: Agustinus Kuncoro
Id = 1
Gender = L
```

I am new to PHP so I am really confused, could I use getter like in Android in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is simply a native PHP Array, so you can work with it respectively:

```
print_r($result_collection->getAsArray()[0]['Id_Dokter'])
print_r($result_collection->getAsArray()[0]['Name_Pasien'])
print_r($result_collection->getAsArray()[0]['Gender'])
```

Or simpler with `echo`, since you need `print_r` only to print arrays:

```
echo $result_collection->getAsArray()[0]['Id_Dokter']
echo $result_collection->getAsArray()[0]['Name_Pasien']
echo $result_collection->getAsArray()[0]['Gender']
```

You can also [iterate each item in array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($result_collection->getAsArray() as &$item)
    echo $item['Id_Dokter'] . "\n";
```